# Schedule Job on jenkins over night

Tags: jenkins, cron

I've read the help in Jenkins itself and also [How to schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins).

In Jenkins you can build a job periodically by defining a cron like syntax with the addition of `H`(for "hash").

So defining

```
H H(0-7) * * *
```

means build once between 0:00 AM and 7:00 AM.

**But how can I define 1 job between 20:00 PM and 7:00 AM of the next day?**

Is there any way?

I tried doing

```
H H(20-23) * * *
H H(0-7) * * *
```

but ofcourse this will build two times.

**Is there any possibility to make it only build once but within this time frame?**

Comment: This has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195208/schedule-nightly-22-03-build-using-jenkins-and-h-the-hash-symbol/55863237#55863237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly an answer but a workarround:

A possible workaround could be to simply use a shifted timezone as e.g.

> My Server has Timezone MEZ which equals GMT+1

so I could probably use something like

```
TZ=Etc/GMT+6
H H(13-23) * * *
```

this will run the build between 8:00 PM and 7:00 AM of the next day.

Comment: If you need to set a GMT-XX timezone, this won't work right now, because of JENKINS-57702, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863237/1847187

Comment: I don't know, worked fine for me for the last two years .. now we are not using Jenkins anymore..